# Figuring out from Hibernate how entity relations are configured

Tags: java, hibernate

Is it possible to retrieve from Hibernate (5) how the relationships between entities are configured?

My **use case** is the following: I have a web service that provides (read) access to data in a relational database. The data consists of multiple entities and some of them are related through foreign keys (the usual one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-one, many-to-many). When requesting data, client can specify a filter and, in the filter, they can freely traverse entity relationships. Something needs to translate the filter into something Hibernate understands though. Currently, we are generating `Criteria`.

As an example, suppose we have 2 entities, `A` and `B`, where the property `A.bees` refers to a collection of `B`. This is mapped in Hibernate by having a foreign-key column in `B` referring to the primary key of `A`. A user can then request all `A`s having at least one `B` with `B.name` starting with `'Bla'`. The request specifies that we're looking for results of type `A`, and its filter part would look something like:

```
<like>
  <property>bees.name</property>
  <literal>Bla*</literal>
</like>
```

The **problem** is: my service does not control the Hibernate mapping and so does not know how the relations are configured or even which entities exist. It just loads the mapping, translates and applies the filter and spits out whatever data gets returned by Hibernate. I cannot change the request content as that is per a specification (actually OGC Filter).

So far, I am able to find the right entities and follow the property path, encountering property `AssociationType`s and `EntityMetadata` along the way and translate all filter elements into individual `Criterion`s. What I am not able to do is to find how the entities are related: in the example, the fact that "`B` has a foreign-key referring to the primary key of `A`". Could anyone tell me how to get that information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I misunderstood how this is supposed to be done in Hibernate. I was using the Criteria API to generate the query that I would write myself:

```
session.createCriteria("A")
       .add(Property.forName("id").in(
                DetachedCriteria.forEntityName("B")
                                .add(Restrictions.like("name", "Bla%"))
                                .setProjection(Projections.property("fk_a"))))
```

The resulting query is (pretty much)

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM A a
 WHERE a.id IN (SELECT b.fk_a
                  FROM B b
                 WHERE b.name LIKE 'Bla%')
```

The problem was that I did not know the names `id` and `fk_a`.

---

What I should have done instead (and am now doing) is simply let Hibernate do the join.

```
session.createCriteria("A")
       .createAlias("B", "b")
       .add(Restrictions.like("b.name", "Bla%"))
       .setResultTransformer(DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer.INSTANCE)
```

The resulting query from this is (pretty much)

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
  FROM A a INNER JOIN B b ON a.id = b.fk_a
 WHERE b.name LIKE 'Bla%')
```

Now I don't need to know the names of the primary and foreign key properties.

The obvious downside of this approach is that more data is transferred from the server to the client as the cartesian product of A's and related B's is returned. We get the expected answer by indicating that we are only interested in distinct root entities. The transformer runs on the client side though, so it really does not help cut down on traffic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I quite understood your database access permissions, but if you can connect to the database, you can use JDBC's DatabaseMetaData class and it's exported keys method:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getExportedKeys(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: I would like to avoid having to talk to the DB directly. The reasons are: 1) Hibernate's configuration already contains all the necessary details and 2) I will be dealing with different types of DB.

Comment: What about hibernate's SessionFactory metaData accessor?
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html
You can access 'all classes metadata' and class (entity) specific.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but I just couldn't find the information I needed without writing special cases for all join-types. I have settled on a different approach.

Comment: @jackrabbit I'm glad you did :)